# Difference between Gentoo and Funtoo

Tags: gentoo, distribution-choice, funtoo

I'm struggling to understand how [Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org) is different from [Gentoo,](http://www.gentoo.org)
 The Funtoo website claims to be an improved version of Gentoo saying this:

> Funtoo Linux features native UTF-8
>   support enabled by default, a
>   git-based, distributed Portage Tree
>   and funtoo overlay, an enhanced
>   Portage with more compact
>   mini-manifest tree, automated imports
>   of new Gentoo changes every 12 hours,
>   GPT/GUID boot support and streamlined
>   boot configuration, enhanced network
>   configuration, up-to-date stable and
>   current Funtoo stages, all built using
>   Funtoo's Metro build tool.

That doesn't seem so different to me.  Are those advantages worth a different distro and are there any downsides?

Comment: I am wondering in what way a random current popular distribution (e.g. Debian) does not have UTF8 enabled by default ...

Comment: @maxschlepzig Gentoo (and subsequently Funtoo) was the first distribution to enable full UTF-8 encoding across the entire system. Although current distributions don't have any problems with UTF-8 now, it was a huge deal back then.

Comment: Other than saving time on building packages, I don't see any "improvement" can't be merged to standard gentoo by DIY.

Comment: "non-constructive"? Maybe the title could be rephrased or else, to give the essential meaning of this question: what are the differences between Gentoo - Funtoo.

Comment: To further support this question's validity, here is a very nice overview of differences page: http://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo_Linux#Differences_between_Funtoo_Linux_and_Gentoo_Linux

Comment: Would I have access(ed) this Q&A before, it would help me (more or less -- does it matter?) understand the differences between Gentoo and Funtoo. I was not aware of it or I did not search well for answers. I decided to give Funtoo a try only after reading Funtoo's wiki-page. Natutally, I did only understand a few things.  Having tried Gentoo 2-3 times in the past, and being not an expert, I was only guessing the "differences". Fortunately, I received quite some support from Funtoo-ers in the #funtoo IRC. I'd appreciate if this answer receives more attention and becomes a real Helper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I an see, reading the Funtoo documentation, another USP here will perhaps be the simplified kernel build in the install.

```
# echo "sys-kernel/sysrescue-std-sources binary" >> /etc/portage/package.use
# emerge sysrescue-std-sources
```

From http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Funtoo_Linux_Installation#Configuring_and_installing_the_Linux_kernel

Answer (score 19):

Oh you will notice the differences...

- a git pull is way faster than the rsync one :)
- the automated kernel build is a real nice feature, you will see
- ebuilds that are maintained by CoreTeam have a cleaner structure, not so much usage of external modules but inline the ebuild so a build gets clean...
- GPT/GUID support is also very nice, cleaner structure of your HDD
- Daily work is like with gentoo
- git based User Overlay is launched, so users can participate in funtoo too, and ebuilds will be directly included into main tree after approval

So you should try it. Also funtoo is doing great work on QA for packages that concern the Core, funtoo tries to build a rock solid, bleeding edge Core System. :)

Answer (score 6):

In day-to-day usage, funtoo feels just as gentoo. The main noticeable difference is in syncing (via git in funtoo) and the contents of default overlays, which for funtoo include `perl-experimental` from what I remember.